# Entity Framework 6 Conventions

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I use the Entity Framework often, but I have one area of confusion I would like to understand better.

If I wanted to have a navigation property in an Entity such as

```
public virtual ExampleObject Example {get;set;}
```

it is also the done thing to have an Id property

```
public int ExampleId {get;set;}
```

My undertsanding is this creates a FK, but if I omit it, the functionality is the same and the FK seems to be created anyway. So, is there a reason for the additional field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never used Entity Framework, nor am I familiar with it's implementation details, but it's quite common that ORMs will not resolve foreign keys into objects unless either they are explicitly instructed to do so or the user tries to access these objects. This makes sense - populating the `Example` property is much more expansive than populating `ExampleId`, since the ID is column of the containing entity's table but for the full `ExampleObject` you need to query another table.

While it seems like `ExampleId` is only useful for resolving the full `ExampleObject`, there can be cases where you need just the ID. For example, if `Student` has `Course` with the `CourseId` foreign key, and `Assignment` also has `Course` with the `CourseId` foreign key, you might want to use `Student`'s `CourseId` directly to get all the `Assignment`s with the same `CourseId`. You don't need the full `Course` object for that.

Comment: Makes sense having the ability to assign an Id rather than entire entity. Thanks.